# How can I use Python to run large SQL queries and export to CSV?

Tags: python, sql, csv, pyodbc

I'm looking to export the result set of a SQL query into a CSV by using Python, the code below works for a small query but when trying on a larger query (sample below) it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

SQL Query - Example code (Very close to actual code but with sensitive info removed):

```
DECLARE @Chosen_Month DATE
SET @Chosen_Month = '2021-01-01';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Base_Data') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Base_Data;

SELECT
     a.region
    ,a.customer_name
    ,SUM(b.transactions) AS transactions
    ,SUM(b.turnover) AS turnover
    ,SUM(b.revenue) AS revenue
INTO
    #Base_Data
FROM
    customer_table AS a
    INNER JOIN transaction_table AS b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
WHERE
    b.trans_date = @Chosen_Month
GROUP BY
    a.region
    ,a.customer_name

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Ranked_Data') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Ranked_Data;

SELECT
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY transactions DESC) AS trans_rank
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY turnover DESC) AS turnover_rank
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS revenue_rank
FROM
    #Base_Data
    
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Ranked_Data
WHERE
    revenue_rank <= 50
ORDER BY 
    revenue_rank ASC
```

I tried looking around to maybe split the SQL query into multiple executes and avoid running these null outputs but couldn't get to a working stage. How can I account for large queries that have objects like scalar variables running throughout as well? I'm fairly new to Python and would appreciate any help on this! Python code below:

```
import pyodbc
import csv

new_file_path = r'S:\Andy\Python\testdump.csv'
query_path = r'S:\Andy\Python\testquery.sql'

def read(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(query_path, 'r') as sql_query_file:
        raw_data = cursor.execute(sql_query_file.read())
        
    with open(new_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_out = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_out.writerow([i[0] for i in raw_data.description])
        for row in raw_data:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
            print("Finished export")
            
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={Driver_name_here};"
    "Server=server_name_here;"
    "Database=database_name_here;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)

read(conn)
conn.close()
```

Comment: It'll be _very_ hard for anyone to help you with this question without a reference to the query you're executing. The fact you're mentioning the query "includes semi colons" suggests `cursor.execute` isn't returning any results for at least one of those statements (which is why the `for` loop fails). Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @crcvd I've added a close example to the SQL query that I was using, hope this helps

Comment: Also SQL Server has [common table expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions), no need to swap something into temp tables manually. Let the optimizer decide when to swap the data.

Comment: As of [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) `cursor.execute` does not return anything: *Return values are not defined*. So it is not iterable. But in pyodbc doc it is described as it returns the same cursor itself, so it may be confusing. You need `fetchmany` calls to get the data in chunks and write that chuncks into file.

Answer (score 2):

Consider pure SQL with CTEs and parameterization on date and avoid any temp tables. Regarding large amount of data, you might be experiencing timeout issues. See [**`pyodbc.connection`** docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#timeout) on use of `timeout` argument.

**SQL**

```sql
WITH Base_Data AS (
    SELECT
          a.region
        , a.customer_name
        , SUM(b.transactions) AS transactions
        , SUM(b.turnover) AS turnover
        , SUM(b.revenue) AS revenue
    FROM
        customer_table AS a
        INNER JOIN transaction_table AS b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
    WHERE
        b.trans_date = ?        -- PARAM PLACEHOLDER
    GROUP BY
          a.region
        , a.customer_name
), Ranked_Data AS (
    SELECT
        , *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY transactions DESC) AS trans_rank
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY turnover DESC) AS turnover_rank
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY revenue DESC) AS revenue_rank
    FROM
        Base_Data
)
    
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Ranked_Data
WHERE
    revenue_rank <= 50
ORDER BY 
    revenue_rank ASC
```

**Python**

```py
def sql_to_csv(conn):
    # COMBINE FILE CONTEXT MANAGERS
    with open(query_path, 'r') as sql_query_file, \
         open(new_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
       
        # BIND PARAM TO QUERY
        raw_data = cursor.execute(sql_query_file.read(), ['2020-01-01'])
        
        csv_out = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_out.writerow([i[0] for i in raw_data.description])

        for row in raw_data:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
         print("Finished export")     # DE-INDENT STATUS PRINT OUTSIDE LOOP

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "Driver={Driver_name_here};"
    "Server=server_name_here;"
    "Database=database_name_here;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;",
    timeout = 3                       # ADJUST ACCORDINGLY
)
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:                                  # EXCEPTION HANDLING TO ALWAYS CLOSE DB OBJECTS
    sql_to_csv(conn)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the goal would be ultimately to have a template that acts as a process for running existing queries with multiple parameters. So changing the query_path and new_file_path variables rather than multiple different SQL variables in the code for each query would be preferable, is that possible?

Comment: Hmmm...are you asking a new question? Let's stay on topic to current specific issue. A more illustrative example would be needed for your later question (too much for comments, so a new question).

Comment: IIUC - why not pass `query_path` and `new_file_path` variables into `sql_to_csv()` method: `sql_to_csv(query_path, new_file_path)`?